# How do I catch global exceptions?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, exception

Is there a way to catch **global** "crashing" app exceptions like objc_exception_throw, EXC_ARITHMETIC etc. in code? I need that because I want to do some things before the app gets killed by the system.

Comment: `objc_exception_throw` is not an exception. It is the function that throws Objective-C exceptions. Similarly, `EXC_ARITHMETIC` is not an Objective-C exception; it is a Mach (kernel) exception, meaning that your app tried to do something completely invalid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set a handler for any uncaught exception by using `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler`.

The relevant docs from Apple are here: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Exceptions/Concepts/UncaughtExceptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000056-BAJDDGGD