# Objective-C Exception Handling: "Divided by Zero Exception" is not getting caught

Tags: objective-c, ios, exception

I have the following code in my program.

```
@try {

    float result =  4 / 0; // LINE 1

} @catch (NSException *e) {

    NSLog(@"Exception : %@", e);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected an exception to be caught in LINE 1 and thrown to the `@catch` block. But the execution aborts at *LINE 1* showing `EXC_ARITHMETIC` in console.

What am I doing wrong here? What necessary things I have to do to do exception handling?

Comment: Why are you trying to catch a divide-by-zero exception rather than checking that the divisor is non-zero?

Answer (score 4):

`EXC_ARITHMETIC` is a type of low-level exception known as a "[signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_%28computing%29)". The only way to catch them is to register a signal handler, for example:

```
#include<signal.h>
void handler(int signal) {
    if (signal == FPE_FLTDIV)
        printf("Divide by 0 exception\n");
}

signal(SIGFPE, handler);
```

However, the only safe thing to do in such a handler is clean up any resources and exit cleanly.

Comment: Actually, the only safe thing to do in such a handler is pretty much nothing (print a message and crash).   Signal handlers will be executed on a random thread in an undefined state such that you pretty much can't do anything without risk of indeterminate behavior.

Comment: Mike Ash wrote an extensive article on signal handling and its pitfalls. http://mikeash.com/pyblog//friday-qa-2011-04-01-signal-handling.html

Answer (score 1):

Divide by zero is not an NSException.

Give this a try (I never tried though):

```
@try {

    float result =  4 / 0; // LINE 1

} @catch (NSException *e) {

    NSLog(@"Exception : %@", e);
    return 0;
}
@catch (id ue) {

    //DIVIDE BY ZERO ATTEMPT MAY ENDUP HERE
    NSLog(@"Exception : %@", ue);
    return 0;
}
```

====== EDIT =======

Turns out divide by zero is not a obj-c exception. But seems you can catch such exceptions globally.

[How do I catch global exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826351/how-do-i-catch-global-exceptions)

Comment: Oh.. I thought "Divide by zero" is an NSException.. I tried your solution, its not working though.

Answer (score 0):

[Exceptions List](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Concepts/PredefinedExceptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000057-BCIGHECA) and division by zero isn't a predefined exception. Also, to know the type of exception, you should send `name` message to the exception object.

```
NSLog(@"Exception : %@", [ e name ] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually  float result =  4 / 0;  would never raise any kind of signal or exception (xcode, LLVM). No idea why it just silently returns inf into result.

Answer (score 0):

"4 / 0" is an expression with known literals, which can be very easily computed by compile time -- therefore there will be no runtime exception on that...

Comment: So you're saying that this is caught at *compile time* rather than *run time*, and so execution is aborted at the start of the file?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the LLVM 5.1 compiler. In a *.m file just tried the line

```
float result = 4 / 0;
```

and

```
int result = 4 / 0;
```

and both give the result to be zero. But, because both contain the expression 4 / 0 which is integer division by zero regardless of the variable definition type, the compiler only gives a warning. All other compilers that I have used would have given an error from this expression.

The C language only specifies that integer division by zero is undefined. The compilers used in this case apparently define the result to be zero. This is a good example of why you should never depend on undefined behavior behaving the way you expect.